# ClassNotFoundException when the class is there?

Tags: android, eclipse, classnotfoundexception

I'm a bit stuck on this. Android is throwing a `ClassNotFoundException` even though there is such a class.

```
04-20 09:07:50.179: E/AndroidRuntime(525): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 09:07:50.179: E/AndroidRuntime(525): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.company.app/com.company.app.Main}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.app.Main
04-20 09:07:50.179: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
04-20 09:07:50.179: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
04-20 09:07:50.179: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-20 09:07:50.179: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
04-20 09:07:50.179: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-20 09:07:50.179: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-20 09:07:50.179: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-20 09:07:50.179: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 09:07:50.179: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-20 09:07:50.179: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-20 09:07:50.179: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-20 09:07:50.179: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-20 09:07:50.179: E/AndroidRuntime(525): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.app.Main
04-20 09:07:50.179: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
04-20 09:07:50.179: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
04-20 09:07:50.179: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
04-20 09:07:50.179: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
04-20 09:07:50.179: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
04-20 09:07:50.179: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  ... 11 more
```

There is such a class called `Main` in `Main.java`.

`public class Main extends FragmentActivity` which is in the package `com.company.app`.

It was working before but when I went back to work on the app today it just stopped working. I don't know what happened.

It is defined correctly in the Manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Main" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Few things I've tried:**

- Restarting Eclipse
- Restarting the emulator
- Uninstalling and reinstalling the app in the emulator
- Cleaning the project.
- Checking if `gen` and `src` is in the `Source` tab of the build path.

As it looks right now, I may have to abandon the current project and start from scratch.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

The app works if `Main` extends `Activity` instead of `FragmentActivity`. Perhaps it is something with the Android Support package?

**UPDATE 2:**

I'm pretty sure it is. When I don't use the support package and I use the normal `Fragment` classes in Android 3.0 and up, the app works fine.

---

The problem is now fixed. :)

For some reason the Android support package removed itself from the `/libs` directory in the project and it was referencing it from an external location (outside the `workspace` directory).

I will mark Abdu Egal's first answer as correct as he directed me on the right track.

Comment: Can you show code of `Main.java`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is an error in the onCreate of your main activity. Did you provide an onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) if so , try to clear it and see if it works then.

If that does not work, try to use extend Activity instead of extend FrameActivity.

Good luck

Comment: I tried commenting out the whole of `onCreate` but I still had the problem. Changing from `FragmentActivity` to `Activity` DID work though! But I have to use `FragmentActivity` because my whole app is based on Fragments. Perhaps it's something with the Android Support package?

Comment: Did you use this package: android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
or something else, there is a posibility that there are multiple classes (in different packages) with the name FragmentActivity.

Comment: Yes. `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;`

Comment: As said in my answer, the problem is now fixed. :)

For some reason the Android support package removed itself from the `/libs` directory in the project and it was referencing it from an external location (outside the `workspace` directory).

I will mark your answer as correct as you directed me on the right track.

Comment: i have the same issue, and i tried all said here..but still there is problem.

Answer (score 0):

From your quition detail i assume that you forgot to declare your FrameActivity into AndroidManifest.xml , kindly check your AndroidManifest.xml file entry.

Comment: `FragmentActivity` is not a custom class I wrote. It is included in Android. (I'm using the one in the Android Support package)

Comment: Do I still have to declare it in the Manifest?

Comment: well i belive that if
 it is not your default activity then you must make an entry in manifest file.

Comment: Only activities you have an intent to must be declared!

Answer (score 0):

I think you used the FragmentActivity the wrong way, I guess FragmentActivities should be a part of a normal activity, see below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <fragment
        android:name="com.mamlambo.tutorial.tutlist.TutListFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tutlist_fragment"
        android:layout_weight="45">
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:name="com.mamlambo.tutorial.tutlist.TutViewerFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tutview_fragment"
        android:layout_weight="55">
    </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

Taken from this link (part 9)

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/

Comment: I'll try this. But why did it work before and suddenly stop working?

Comment: Ok, I had a little try and it's something wrong when using the Android Support package. When using the normal fragment classes in Android 3.0 and up, the app works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project folder => Properties => Java Build Path => Order and Export => check the box "Android Private Libraries" if not checked. Make a clean. And it works !

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with MobilTuts sample, problem was with support library.
I have changed the build target to a higher API than 10, something like 15 for example, and then all errors vanished.

**Project Properties --> Android --> Project Build Target --> Set it to 15 .e.g**

**Recommendation:** set MIN API inside manifest to 8 at lest.