# passing data from database to activity

Tags: android, database, google-maps

I'm developing an app that displays location on a map when I press the button.

However, i want to get the latitude and longitude data, that this button is receiving, from a database.

I already have an activity named "DetaljiProizvoda" that gets details of items from the database and I've added (in file DatabaseHelper.java) columns of int type for latitude and longitude in database.

I want to pass latitude and longitude data to GMapsActivity.java file and use them to show the location for each item on map.

I get these errors in LogCat, please help:

```
09-23 18:07:52.986: E/AndroidRuntime(22995): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 18:07:52.986: E/AndroidRuntime(22995): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
09-23 18:07:52.986: E/AndroidRuntime(22995):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3044)
09-23 18:07:52.986: E/AndroidRuntime(22995):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
09-23 18:07:52.986: E/AndroidRuntime(22995):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
09-23 18:07:52.986: E/AndroidRuntime(22995):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
09-23 18:07:52.986: E/AndroidRuntime(22995):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-23 18:07:52.986: E/AndroidRuntime(22995):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-23 18:07:52.986: E/AndroidRuntime(22995):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-23 18:07:52.986: E/AndroidRuntime(22995):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 18:07:52.986: E/AndroidRuntime(22995):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-23 18:07:52.986: E/AndroidRuntime(22995):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-23 18:07:52.986: E/AndroidRuntime(22995):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-23 18:07:52.986: E/AndroidRuntime(22995):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-23 18:07:52.986: E/AndroidRuntime(22995): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-23 18:07:52.986: E/AndroidRuntime(22995):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 18:07:52.986: E/AndroidRuntime(22995):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-23 18:07:52.986: E/AndroidRuntime(22995):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
09-23 18:07:52.986: E/AndroidRuntime(22995):    ... 11 more
09-23 18:07:52.986: E/AndroidRuntime(22995): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-23 18:07:52.986: E/AndroidRuntime(22995):    at hr.punctum.LociranjePonudaProizvoda.DetaljiProizvoda.changeActivity(DetaljiProizvoda.java:66)
09-23 18:07:52.986: E/AndroidRuntime(22995):    ... 14 more
```

**DetaljiProizvoda.java**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detalji_proizvoda);

        proizvodId = getIntent().getIntExtra("PROIZVODI_ID", 0);
        SQLiteDatabase db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT proizv._id, proizv.naziv, proizv.tvrtka, proizv.cijena, proizv.kategorija, proizv.telefonTvrtke, proizv.adresaTvrtke, proizv.latitude, proizv.longitude FROM proizvodi proizv LEFT OUTER JOIN proizvodi mgr ON proizv._id = mgr._id WHERE proizv._id = ?", 
                new String[]{""+proizvodId});

        if (cursor.getCount() == 1)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            naziv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.naziv);
            naziv.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("naziv"))); 

            kategorija = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kategorija);
            kategorija.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("kategorija")));

            tvrtka = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvrtka);
            tvrtka.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("tvrtka")));

            telefonTvrtke = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.telefonTvrtke);
            telefonTvrtke.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("telefonTvrtke")));

            adresaTvrtke = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.adresaTvrtke);
            adresaTvrtke.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("adresaTvrtke")));

        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close(); 

    }

      public void changeActivity(View view) { 

        Intent intent = new Intent(DetaljiProizvoda.this, GMapsActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra("PROIZVODI_ID", cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            intent.putExtra("PROIZVODI_LATITUDE", cursor.getColumnIndex("latitude"));
            intent.putExtra("PROIZVODI_LONGITUDE", cursor.getColumnIndex("longitude"));
            startActivity(intent);                    

        }                    

    }
```

**GMapsActivity.java**

public class GMapsActivity extends MapActivity {

```
private MapView mapView;
protected int latitudeE6;
protected int longitudeE6;  



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gmaps_layout);

    latitudeE6 = getIntent().getIntExtra("PROIZVODI_LATITUDE", 0);       
    longitudeE6 = getIntent().getIntExtra("PROIZVODI_LONGITUDE", 0);      

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);       
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
    CustomItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);

    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(latitudeE6, longitudeE6);
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Dobrodošli u " , "tvrtku Protis");

    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

    MapController mapController = mapView.getController();

    mapController.animateTo(point);
    mapController.setZoom(18);

}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
```

}

**ListaProizvoda.java**

```
package hr.punctum.LociranjePonudaProizvoda;    

public class ListaProizvoda extends ListActivity {

    protected EditText searchText;
    protected SQLiteDatabase db;
    protected Cursor cursor;
    protected ListAdapter adapter;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
        searchText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.searchText);

    }    

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    //kreiranje metode Search za pretraživanje proizvoda u bazi podataka
    public void search(View view) {
        // slijedeci sql query vraca rezultat iz baze svih zapisa koji pocinju na slovo uneseno u search polje
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, naziv, tvrtka, cijena FROM proizvodi WHERE naziv LIKE ?", 
                        new String[]{searchText.getText().toString() + "%"}); 
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.proizvodi_list_artikl,cursor,new String[] {"naziv", "tvrtka", "cijena"},new int[] {R.id.naziv, R.id.tvrtka, R.id.cijena});

        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //kreiranje Intenta za komunikaciju s drugim activity-om
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetaljiProizvoda.class);
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
        //slanje varijable
        intent.putExtra("PROIZVODI_ID", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "proizvodidb";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 4);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS proizvodi (" +
                        "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                        "naziv TEXT, " +
                        "tvrtka TEXT, " +
                        "cijena TEXT, " +
                        "kategorija TEXT, " +
                        "telefonTvrtke TEXT, " +
                        "adresaTvrtke TEXT, " +
                        "latitude INTEGER, " +
                        "longitude INTEGER)";

        db.execSQL(sql);

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put("naziv", "Nikon D800");
        values.put("tvrtka", "MagazinRS");
        values.put("cijena", "21600");
        values.put("kategorija", "fotoaparati");
        values.put("telefonTvrtke", "454562542");
        values.put("adresaTvrtke", "Laniste 1B");
        values.put("latitude", 458011234);
        values.put("longitude", 159520583);
        db.insert("proizvodi", "tvrtka", values);   

        ....        

    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS proizvodi");
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

**detalji_proizvoda.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/naziv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/kategorija"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvrtka"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/telefonTvrtke"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/adresaTvrtke"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>      
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:onClick="changeActivity"
        android:text="@string/prikazi_lokaciju"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

new logcat (after closing cursor after changeActivity method):

```
09-23 20:04:30.050: E/AndroidRuntime(995): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 20:04:30.050: E/AndroidRuntime(995): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
09-23 20:04:30.050: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3044)
09-23 20:04:30.050: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
09-23 20:04:30.050: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
09-23 20:04:30.050: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
09-23 20:04:30.050: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-23 20:04:30.050: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-23 20:04:30.050: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-23 20:04:30.050: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 20:04:30.050: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-23 20:04:30.050: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-23 20:04:30.050: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-23 20:04:30.050: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-23 20:04:30.050: E/AndroidRuntime(995): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-23 20:04:30.050: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 20:04:30.050: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-23 20:04:30.050: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
09-23 20:04:30.050: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  ... 11 more
09-23 20:04:30.050: E/AndroidRuntime(995): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-23 20:04:30.050: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at hr.punctum.LociranjePonudaProizvoda.DetaljiProizvoda.changeActivity(DetaljiProizvoda.java:65)
09-23 20:04:30.050: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  ... 14 more
```

**logcat:**

```
09-23 22:46:14.652: E/AndroidRuntime(680): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 22:46:14.652: E/AndroidRuntime(680): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{hr.punctum.LociranjePonudaProizvoda/hr.punctum.LociranjePonudaProizvoda.ListaProizvoda}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hr.punctum.LociranjePonudaProizvoda.ListaProizvoda
09-23 22:46:14.652: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
09-23 22:46:14.652: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
09-23 22:46:14.652: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
09-23 22:46:14.652: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
09-23 22:46:14.652: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-23 22:46:14.652: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-23 22:46:14.652: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-23 22:46:14.652: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 22:46:14.652: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-23 22:46:14.652: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-23 22:46:14.652: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-23 22:46:14.652: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-23 22:46:14.652: E/AndroidRuntime(680): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hr.punctum.LociranjePonudaProizvoda.ListaProizvoda
09-23 22:46:14.652: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
09-23 22:46:14.652: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
09-23 22:46:14.652: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
09-23 22:46:14.652: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
09-23 22:46:14.652: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
09-23 22:46:14.652: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: first try checking if the cursor is null instead of (cursor.getCount() == 1)

Comment: why should i do that? I mean why cursor has to be null?

Comment: if there is no data that is obtained then the cursor will have no data indirectly it will be null and using cursor.getCount() may trouble you

Comment: i see, thanks. this doesn't solve the problem, though.

Comment: or else i think you are calling changeActivity() outside the class without creating an object for the class.
where did you use changeActivity()?

Comment: I've used changeActivity in DetaljiProizvoda.java. You can see code here on this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You close your cursor at end of onCreate() method. Then in method changeActivity() you try to use it.

Comment: I've changed this but my app is still crushing when entering last activity (GMapsActivity), i.e. when displaying map location. can you write full code?

Comment: Could you provide a new logcat (a one after fixing problem with cursor)?

Comment: i did that at start as i can see. i closed cursor at the end of onCreate() method and then i tried to use it in changeActivity(). So what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You should not close cursor at the end onCreate method. When you do that and use  intent.putExtra("PROIZVODI_ID",cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));   you get the error  at hr.punctum.LociranjePonudaProizvoda.DetaljiProizvoda.changeActivity(DetaljiProizvoda.java:66.   Fix that in your code and then provide a new logcat if app still crashes

Comment: i've added new logcat. Now i've closed cursor at the end of changeActivity method. db.close() is where it was before, is that ok?

Comment: Where do you use a class named ListaProizvoda?

Comment: this is first activity that is passing intent to second activity("DetaljiProizvoda.java"). I've added it too so you can see it.

Comment: Instead Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetaljiProizvoda.class); try Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetaljiProizvoda.class); and make the same change in changeActivityMethod()

Comment: ok, i've added this, but i am still geting logcat errors as before. i think there is other problem beause app was working perfectly fine (even with cursor closing at earlier position) till changes in changeActivity method, i.e. trying to put extra data - latitude and longitude and passing them to GMaps activity which would then display map location based on related latitude and longitude records in database. I can't solve this problem.

Comment: You are defining a new variable of type Cursor called _cursor_ in onCreate method  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(...)
You can't use it in changeActivity(). So define a field called _cursor_ in DetaljiProizvodaActivity and in onCreate() use just cursor = db.rawQuery( ... ); Then you can use in changeActivity()

Comment: It's a member of the class. just _Cursor cursor_ ;

Comment: now app is not crashing but i see only blue screen on map without any tiles, there is also displayed overlay icon. i suppose i didn't pass correctly latitude and longitude parameters from database to that activity, cause app was working before and was correctly displaying map location (i generated key and all stuff that is needed for displaying map); in short, i want to pass different latitude and longitude parameters depending on their values in database and display them (as different locations) on map.

Comment: You are not passing _latitude_ and _longitude_.You are passing column indices.   intent.putExtra("PROIZVODI_LATITUDE", cursor.getColumnIndex("latitude")); You should query db in GMapsActivity to get latitude using extras from intent or to pass a latitude value from DetaljiProizvoda. And you could accept one of my answers :)

Comment: maybe i am doing it wrong, i want to pass latitude and longitude values from database (as int values, i declared them as integer type of data when creating database). I tried to use getIntent().getIntExtra to get those extras as you can see from code but with no success.

Comment: But you are not passing real longitude and latitude. You are using Intent.putExtra("PROIZVODI_LATITUDE",cursor.getColumnIndex("latitude"));   so you pass an column index. It has value of 1 or 2.

Comment: yes, i see. so can you tell how to pass real longitude and latitude, that is what i need:-)

Comment: Intent.putExtra("PROIZVODI_LATITUDE",cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("latitude")));

Comment: app is getting crashed now. I've added newest logcat and databasehelper.java file where i created database.

Comment: yes,ofcourse. <activity android:label="@string/app_name"            
            android:name=".ListaProizvoda" > intent filter tag ...</activity>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242969/classnotfoundexception-when-the-class-is-there

Comment: app is not chrashing anymore, but only what i get is blue background when on map. i used this for getting intent extras (in GMapsActivity file): latitudeE6 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("PROIZVODI_LATITUDE", 0); longitudeE6 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("PROIZVODI_LONGITUDE", 0); is this right?

Comment: map was displayed correctly, i've put random latitude and longitude so emulator displayed ocean on map, therefore blue :-) it seems to be working now, map is showing different locations, but i've to check if it's displaying wanted locations.

Comment: app is fully working now, it displays correct locations (i removed zeros in getIntent().getExtras().getInt(....,0) and corrected typo in intent.putExtra code, latitude was mentioned twice there. only error i get now is 09-24 13:29:24.048: W/CursorWrapperInner(1047): Cursor finalized without prior close(). i closed cursors as i can see.

Comment: I can't see it is closed in ListaProizvoda activity. You could put in in onDestroy() of that activity

Comment: in the meantime i've closed it there too (inside method onListItemClick) but i still get that error. i will try to put it in onDestroy()

Comment: saying that, it's better to use startManagingCursor(cursor) (althogh it is deprecated method) than closing cursor in onListItemClick() because later approach crashes app. first way app at least works and is not crashing.